# Group by on a really long query?

Tags: sql, group-by, case

My query because it's mandatory to add COD and DES on GROUP BY when I used them on CASE WHEN:

```
Select SUM(UNIVERSO)
CASE WHEN A.COD IN  ('A','B') THEN 5
  WHEN A.DES IN  ('D','E') THEN 5
END UNIVERSO,
FROM TABLEX
GROUP BY A.COD, A.DES
```

The result I'm getting:

The two columns at the right are "hidden" as I didn't write them on select but appear on group by

```
UNIVERSO [ COD  DES
    5       A    D
    5       B    E
  100       C    M ]
```

What I want:

```
UNIVERSO
  110
```

I don't need the resulting rows of the code (i have the right quantity on columns though), neverthless I do need the conditions on case when.

I thought on making another group by outside the whole table but it's really long (even to do it as a temporary table). Maybe there's another command I do not know about

Comment: Please can you explain, by providing sample data, your SQL attempt and the required result, what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @NickW Hi! Sorry, I will write the question again. 

My query because it's mandatory to add COD and DES on GROUP BY:

     Select *
     CASE WHEN A.COD IN  ('A','B') THEN 0
          WHEN A.DES IN  ('D','E') THEN '0
     END UNIVERSO,
     FROM TABLEX
     GROUP BY A.COD, A.DES

The result I'm getting:

     UNIVERSO  COD  DES
         0      A    D
         0      B    E
       100      C    M

What I want:

     UNIVERSO
       100

I don't need the two variables (nor the resulting columns or rows of the code), neverthless I do need the conditions on case when

Comment: Update the question, don't add to it with an answer unless it's an actual answer.

Comment: I'm a little confused since the results in your question don't seem to match the  schema select statement above it and the 'UNIVERSO' field from your select statement doesn't seem right...

You're using GROUP BY, but you're not showing us what is being aggregated. If the 'UNIVERSO' field in your results is an aggregation, then you will need to use the HAVING clause, otherwise you can remove the unrequired rows with a simple WHERE clause?

Comment: @rory Yup, I want to aggregate UNIVERSO, sorry for not making it clear. I need the rows, but as aggregate results so I can't remove them. I don't need the result to be so long (3 rows), I need it in less rows (1 row), but with the conditional on case when

Answer (score 2):

Given your confirmation that you're aggregating on UNIVERSO, you can achieve what you're after with something like this (Note that the 'UNIVERSO' needs to be placed with the SUM(CASE WHEN) statement to get the result you appear to be after):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN A.COD IN ('A','B')
    THEN 0 
    WHEN A.DES IN ('D','E') 
    THEN 0 
    ELSE UNIVERSO END) as UNIVERSO_AGG,
FROM TABLEX
GROUP BY A.COD, A.DES
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN A.COD IN ('A','B')
    THEN 0 
    WHEN A.DES IN ('D','E') 
    THEN 0 
    ELSE UNIVERSO END) > 0
```

Comment: Omg I didn't know SUM outside CASE WHEN existed. This helped me so much. Thank you rory :)